# How can i read from a file in C

Tags: c, file, io

How do I read from a file using this function?

```
#include <stdio.h>

char* read_from_file (const char* filename, size_t length)
{
  //I have this so far
  fp = fopen(filename,"r"); // read mode

  if( fp == NULL )
  {
      perror("Error while opening the file.\n");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  /* what goes in here? */

  return NULL;
}
```

I'm trying to implement to the following guidelines:

> - It allocates a char buffer of size length+1.
> - It opens file filename, in read only mode. When it fails to open the file, it deallocates the buffer memory
> - It reads length characters into the buffer, inserts a null character (\0) in the last position, closes the file and returns a pointer to the buffer. When it fails to read length characters, it deallocates the buffer memory, closes the file and returns NULL.

Comment: So, which function do you use to allocate memory (a buffer is a chunk of memory)?  It is better to open the file and only allocate the memory if the file is opened successfully.  You should also check that the memory is allocated successfully, of course.  Which functions can you use to read blocks of data?  Which function is used to free memory?  Which function is used to close the file?  This is all very straight-forward.

Comment: It seems like a very basic matter. Check `malloc`, `fread` and `fclose`

Answer (score 0):

You pretty much included the answer in your question:

1. Allocate a char buffer of size `length`+1.
2. Open the file `filename`, in read only mode. If you fail to open the file, deallocate the buffer and return
3. Read `length` characters into the buffer, inserts a null character (\0) in the last position, close the file and return a pointer to the buffer.
4. If you fail to read `length` characters, deallocate the buffer memory, close the file, and return NULL.